# Is there an elegant way to cycle through a list N times via iteration (like itertools.cycle but limit the cycles)?

Tags: python, iterator

I'd like to cycle through a list repeatedly (N times) via an iterator, so as not to actually store N copies of the list in memory.  Is there a built-in or elegant way to do this without writing my own generator?

Ideally, itertools.cycle(my_list) would have a second argument to limit how many times it cycles...  alas, no such luck.

Comment: I believe that multiplying a list by an integer is not good enough, right?  `[1, 2, 3] * 4`

Comment: @C2H5OH That would create 4 shallow copies of the list (N copies is what is not wanted).

Comment: @Darthfett: Indeed.  That's why it is a comment.  But you will agree that it is the most elegant solution :-P

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
import itertools
it = itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat([1, 2, 3], 5))
print(list(it))
# [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Itertools is a wonderful library. :)

As pointed out in the comments, if you are using *iterators* (instead of lists or similar collections), iterators are exhausted after the first iteration, and so you have to use a slightly different approach to get the expected result.  Note that infinite or excessively long iterators can't be reasonably handled, as you would have to cache the result (requiring infinite or excessive amounts of memory).

This may not be the most efficient implementation (`tee` stores N copies of the iterable's contents):

```
import itertools
it = itertools.chain(*itertools.tee(iter([1, 2, 3]), 5))
print(list(it))
# [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Note this won't work in the case that the first argument to `repeat` is a consumable iterator. For example `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(iter([1, 2, 3]), 2)))` evaluates to `[1, 2, 3]`, not `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`. This is because the iterator gets consumed the first time it is iterated over.

Comment: @user2846495, this is accurate.  It's not truly possible to write a solution for any iterator, as you would need to cache the result, which would cause issues for any infinite generator (you end up wasting an unbounded amount of memory).

Comment: For any finite generator though, `itertools.tee` could be used to create copies of the iterable, which would make it fairly simple to implement with `list(itertools.chain(*itertools.tee(iter([1, 2, 3]), 5)))`

Answer (score 13):

All the other answers are excellent. Another solution would be to use `islice`. This allows you to interrupt the cycle at any point:

```
>>> from itertools import islice, cycle
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list(islice(cycle(l), len(l) * 3))
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
>>> list(islice(cycle(l), 7))
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1]
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know islice worked with values for `stop` that were greater than the length of the iterable.

Comment: @Darthfett, yes, it does. But that's not relevant here; the iterable returned by `cycle` is infinitely long.

Comment: What would be the equivalent in Python 3?

Answer (score 8):

```
itertools.chain.from_iterable(iter(L) for x in range(N))
```

Answer (score 6):

For the special case where you need to iterate over a list several times, this is not too bad.

It does create a list of `n` references to `my_list`, so if `n` is very large it is better to use Darthfelt's answer

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> it.chain(*[my_list]*n)
```

Answer (score 5):

You said that you don't want to write your own generator, but a generator expression would probably be the easiest and most efficient way to accomplish what you're after. It doesn't require any function calls or importing of any modules. `itertools` is a great module, but maybe not necessary in this case?

```
some_list = [1, 2, 3]
cycles = 3
gen_expr = (elem for _ in xrange(cycles) for elem in some_list)
```

or just

```
(elem for _ in xrange(3) for elem in [1, 2, 3])
```

or

```
for elem in (e for _ in xrange(3) for e in [1, 2, 3]):
    print "hoo-ray, {}!".format(elem)
```

Comment: I do like these generator expressions.  They're more compact than I realized they'd be for this pattern. I'll give the answer credit to @Darthfett, since technically I asked for a non-self-rolled generator, but if I could accept two, I'd accept yours as well (and probably others' :-))  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

@Darthfett's answer is documented as an [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes):

```
from itertools import chain, repeat


def ncycles(iterable, n):
    "Returns the sequence elements n times"
    return chain.from_iterable(repeat(tuple(iterable), n))


list(ncycles(["a", "b"], 3))
# ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
```

For convenience, I add that the [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools) library implements this recipe (and many others) for you:

```
import more_itertools as mit


list(mit.ncycles(["a", "b"], 3))
# ['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b']
```