# python repeat list elements in an iterator

Tags: python, python-itertools

Is there any way to create an iterator to repeat elements in a list certain times? For example, a list is given:

```
color = ['r', 'g', 'b']
```

Is there a way to create a iterator in form of `itertools.repeatlist(color, 7)` that can produce the following list?

```
color_list = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'r', 'g', 'b', 'r']
```

Comment: Did you actually try reading the itertools docs before you asked the question?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: note that the other question does *full cycle repeats*; so the OP here would need to be content with multiples of 3.

Comment: @MartijnPieters,  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10325689/2141635, that is pretty much identical to your own answer.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: right, I missed that one. Yet the questions are sufficiently different here, and technically that answer is wrong for that question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Circular list iterator in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416381/circular-list-iterator-in-python)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) together with [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to build your `repeatlist()` function:

```
from itertools import cycle, islice

def repeatlist(it, count):
    return islice(cycle(it), count)
```

This returns a new iterator; call `list()` on it if you must have a list object.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import cycle, islice
>>> def repeatlist(it, count):
...     return islice(cycle(it), count)
...
>>> color = ['r', 'g', 'b']
>>> list(repeatlist(color, 7))
['r', 'g', 'b', 'r', 'g', 'b', 'r']
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation of `cycle` says:

> Note, this member of the toolkit may require significant auxiliary storage (depending on the length of the iterable).

I'm curious why python doesn't provide a more efficient implementation:

```
def cycle(it):
    while True:
        for x in it:
            yield x

def repeatlist(it, count):
    return [x for (i, x) in zip(range(count), cycle(it))]
```

This way, you don't need to save a whole copy of the list. And it works if list is infinitely long.

Comment: Because `itertools.cycle` accepts an `iterable` which might be a generator that can only be generated through once, for example a `map` object. Once it's exhausted, you can't get element from it anymore. Thus your `cycle` will never reach `yield x` again, which makes it an infinite-loop. Try `print(*islice(cycle(map(int, "123")), 20))`