# Is it possible to limit the number of iterations and also store the iterator items in a list using itertools?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-itertools

I have a bunch of lines (over 50 in total) that are to appear in several plots, and I would like to store them using numerous markers. Alas, the number of markers in `matplotlib` is limited to the extent that the number is eclipsed by the number of lines. After spending an hour looking for an answer here, I identified `itertools.cycle` as a potential solution since it allows me to cycle through a series. Say, for example, I want to cycle through five markers:

```
import itertools    
markers = itertools.cycle(('o', 'D', '*', 'X', '+'))
```

However, I soon realized the necessity of limiting the cycle to a certain number (i.e. the number of lines) and storing them in a list because the lines will appear in several plots and I would like for the markers to be consistent. I came across another question ([Is there an elegant way to cycle through a list N times via iteration (like itertools.cycle but limit the cycles)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325494/is-there-an-elegant-way-to-cycle-through-a-list-n-times-via-iteration-like-iter)) that appears to solve the limited part of my problem by:

```
import itertools
n = 50 # number of lines
itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(['o', 'D', '*', 'X', '+'], n))
```

So, now I only need to figure out the storing part of my problem.

- How do I go about both limiting the number of iterations (appears to be solved) and also storing them as items in a list?

If `itertools` is not the most convenient way, I would appreciate if someone could point me in a more convenient direction.

Comment: I'm sure this would be easier to understand and solve if there was an example case with matplotlib that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the itertools.chain is an iterable object I just ran the list function on the result of the itertools.chain.from_iterable constructor like so:

```
import itertools
n = 50 # number of lines
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(['o', 'D', '*', 'X', '+'], n)))
```

And got the result in a list. The list ended up having length 250 because it iterated through the entire series 50 times.

I hope this helps.

Edit:

Of course, if you want to use the list just set a variable to the result like so:

```
var_name = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(['o', 'D', '*', 'X', '+'], n)))
```

Comment: Thank you, @sturdeac. This is basically what I was after. I have been proven an idiot for not trying the most obvious thing... again. I did, however, implement a few modifications, by introducing `n_mark` as the length of the markers, which combined with `n`, limited the length due to `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(markers, math.ceil(n / n_mark))))`.

Comment: Awesome. Cool addition. I'm glad I was able to help!