# Best way to do range(N) * 2 in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

I know that python 3 range no longer produces a list, but a range object.
Is there a best way to do the following in python 3?

```
for i in range(3) * 2:
    print(i)

# 0
# 1
# 2
# 0
# 1
# 2
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325494/is-there-an-elegant-way-to-cycle-through-a-list-n-times-via-iteration-like-iter It shows how to use `itertools` with a list, but I think it should work with a range as well.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it without making a list is to use `chain.from_iterable` and `repeat` from the [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module. This uses O(1) extra space.

```py
>>> from itertools import chain, repeat
>>> for i in chain.from_iterable(repeat(range(3), 2)):
...     print(i)
... 
0
1
2
0
1
2
```

Answer (score 3):

Just make a list from the range:

```
for i in list(range(3)) * 2:
    print(i)
```

Result:

```
0
1
2
0
1
2
```